# SteamVR 2.2b4 SteamVR_Action_Boolean error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steam, steamvr

I've been having a problem with the VR implementation in Unity since steam updated to 2.0 in

Now I'm working with their latest update from Github (2.2b4) and when I add the prefab "player" I am getting a constant error that says:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

And it points me to the file SteamVR_Action_Boolean.cs, I understand the error, it is expecting an assignment of an object somewhere, I just cant work out where. Has anyone had this same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an error from Steam, I had it reported and now is all fixed in their new formal release.